# Passing flags to Django call_command

Tags: python, django

How do you pass a flag to Django's `call_command()`?

I thought it was simply `call_command('command', flag=True)`, but this doesn't work in Django 1.11.

I'm trying to run `manage.py collectstatic --noinput` from inside a unittest, but even though I'm calling it like:

```
call_command('collectstatic', noinput=True)
```

my unittest keeps hanging because collectstatic prompts for input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking into Django [collectstatic](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py) source

> ```
> parser.add_argument(
>     '--noinput', '--no-input', action='store_false', dest='interactive',
>     help="Do NOT prompt the user for input of any kind.",
> )
> ```

It is visible that destination argument is interactive so the following value should be set to False

```
call_command('collectstatic', interactive=False)
```